# How do I auto scroll text advertsiment using qt?

Tags: qt

I develop a mobile application, where I want to auto scroll some text as my advertisement. I read from some forum where they mention its a ticker, but I try it but but I failed, so please help me to solve my problem,

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have access to the QScrollBar you want to move, you can do it like this: Use a single-shot QTimer to define how often you move the scroll. Connect the `timeout()` signal of the timer to a slot written by you which calls the QScrollBar `setSliderPosition` method. If you need to scroll further, restart the QTimer. 
The slot you connect the timer's signal to would look like:

```
void scroll()
{
    new_scroll_offset = ...; // compute scroll offset here (possibly from old scroll offset)
    scroll_bar->setSliderPosition(new_scroll_offset);

    if (/* can scroll further */)
    { 
        timer->start();
    }
}
```

It can also be done with a multiple shot timer in a similar fashion